# How to take backup of PostgreSQL 9.4 database to remote server using pg_basebackup?

Tags: postgresql, backup, postgresql-9.4, pg-dump

We want to take the logical and base backup on different server machine in the network. Currently both backups are running on same server machine causing space issues. We have the scripts in place what are the necessary changes we need to make in the scripts to implement the same. Do we need to run the script on DB server machine and direct the backup on other network machine or do we need to run the script of another network machine (Network machine have the same version of PostgreSQL installed on it). Please guide me through the standard procedure under best practices.

Comment: Both tools (`pg_basebackup` and `pg_dump`) can run on any computer that can connect to the server that should be backed up.

Comment: So u mean I have to run the scripts on destination machine rather running on Main server ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Look at the `-h` and `-p` options.